# iText table SetKeepTogether repeating header row

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I try to make my table and the header rows SetKeepTogether(true), but this happens
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgSX5.png),i tried to set all cells SetKeepTogether (true) but it still makes the page break in the row.
Is SetKeepWithNext will help here?

```
clsPDFHeader handler = new clsPDFHeader(dtTestHeader(), document);
pdfDocument.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, handler);
document.SetMargins(30 + handler.GetTableHeight(), 36, 36, 36);
Table tblChcklist = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(new float[] { 4, 35, 20, 20, 20 })).SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE).SetHorizontalAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).UseAllAvailableWidth().SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, false)).SetFontSize(10);

foreach (DataRow drS in dtS.CopyToDataTable().Rows)
{
                    tblChcklist = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(new float[] { 4, 35, 20, 20, 20 })).SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE).SetHorizontalAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).UseAllAvailableWidth().SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, false)).SetKeepTogether(true);
                    tblChcklist.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(2, 1).Add(new Paragraph($"No.").SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).SetHorizontalAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)));
                    tblChcklist.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(2, 1).Add(new Paragraph($"Seccion {drS["nombreSeccion"]}").SetBold()));
                    tblChcklist.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("Si").SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)));
                    tblChcklist.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("No").SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)));
                    tblChcklist.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("No Aplica").SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)));
                    var dtP = business.getPreguntasRevision().AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("idCatTipoChecklist") == idChecklist && r.Field<int>("idCatCheckListSeccion") == (int)drS["idCatCheckListSeccion"]);
                    if (dtP.Any())
                    {
                    int count = 1;
                    foreach (DataRow drP in dtP.CopyToDataTable().Rows)
                    {
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(2, 1).Add(handler.getCell($"{count}", TextAlignment.CENTER)));
                    tblChcklist.AddCell($"{drP["Pregunta"].ToString().Trim()}");
                    //3-4
                    //Si
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(handler.getCell($"\u0037", TextAlignment.CENTER).SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.ZAPFDINGBATS)));
                    //No
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(handler.getCell($"\u0037", TextAlignment.CENTER).SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.ZAPFDINGBATS)));
                    //NA
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(handler.getCell($"\u0037", TextAlignment.CENTER).SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.ZAPFDINGBATS)));
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(1, 5).Add(new Paragraph($"Comentario: ")));
                    count++;
                    }
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(0, 0).Add(new Paragraph()));
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(0, 0).Add(new Paragraph($"Responsable").SetBold()));
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(0, 0).Add(new Paragraph($"Firma").SetBold()));
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(0, 0).Add(new Paragraph($"Fecha Compromiso").SetBold()));
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(0, 0).Add(new Paragraph($"Fecha Terminación").SetBold()));
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(0, 0).Add(new Paragraph()));
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(0, 0).Add(new Paragraph($"Plantilla CIMS - Checklist")));
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(0, 0).Add(new Paragraph(String.Empty)));
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(0, 0).Add(new Paragraph($"{DateTime.Now}")));
                    tblChcklist.AddCell(new Cell(0, 0).Add(new Paragraph($"{DateTime.Now}")));
                    }
                    document.Add(tblChcklist.SetMarginBottom(10));
}
```

Comment: Is the table larger than 1 full page?

Comment: Yes, I decided to make a table per record because i read that on large table does not respect it,and now with SetKeepTogether(true) respects it.

Comment: What's the behavior you're looking for?  If the table is larger than a page, it has to be split _somewhere_.